# Setting 'index' property for all sub-fields of a field

Tags: elasticsearch, pyes

When trying to add term facets, I face the issue that the terms get tokenized into separate words. For example, if an attribute (field) `Kind` has values `medium kind of shirt` and `large kind of shirt`, the terms become - `medium`, `large`, `kind`, `of`, `shirt`.

To fix this, it was suggested that I change the mapping to include `"index": "not_analyzed"` for each attribute field. The problem is that the mapping is generated dynamically, for example -:

```
"attributes": {
   "properties": {
      "kind": {
         "type": "string"
      },
      "color": {
         "type": "string"
      },
      "size": {
         "type": "string"
      }
   }
}
```

Simply setting the `"not_analyzed"` bit inside `"attributes"` will not do. Is there a way to set the index attribute for each sub-field inside the `attributes` field?

Comment: If it's generated dynamically, then you should be able to define a dynamic template for it where you can specify the `index` attribute. See this for details on dynamic mapping: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-dynamic-mapping.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Andrei's comment, I was able to figure out how to apply the setting.

I added a `dynamic_templates` section to my mapping as follows -:

```
"dynamic_templates": [
    {
        "string_template": {
            "path_match": "attributes.*",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

This does the trick, and now each sub-field with `"string"` type has their `"index"` setting as `"not_analyzed"`. The terms are no longer tokenized.